# Can an employer exclude you from all meetings during the notice period?

Tags: manager, germany, conflict, startup

After I refused to resign, I got put on my notice period which is 3 months. I have been excluded from all online and onsite meetings in the company, but I'm expected to report to my boss via chat, fill in timesheets with detailed notes of what I've worked on. Selecting options from the timesheet form is no longer enough. If I can't join meetings then they should have just put me on [garden leave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_leave).

When they were trying to strong-arm me into quitting, my manager removed my GitHub access and IDE license, which prevented me from doing my work. It took a day for my access to be reinstated. The manager has also been very rude.

What can an employer do and not do during an employee's notice period? For example, can they exclude you from all meetings?

Comment: This is a naïve question.  Where did you get the idea that you can attend a meeting without the invitation ?

Comment: Why do you care? What are they going to do if you don’t fill in a detailed time sheet? Fire you?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri One could easily argue that this question _"does not show any research effort"_.

Comment: Looking at the previous questions and possibly also because of the user's name (though that might be a misinterpretation, but "Duzi" in a lot of Southern German dialects means what Americans would call a pacifier and Brits a dummy) I get the impression that the user is indeed very young and very inexperienced rather than just 'naive'.

Comment: @Marianne013 The OP's oldest post was in Jan, 2022. It looks like they already worked for a company for a while. I would say the OP has around 2 years experience. I can hardly call OP "very inexperienced".

Comment: Had a bit of a look at your [question history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/132621/duzii2?tab=questions&sort=newest).  I understand [Germany provides](https://www.euroguidance.eu/guidance-system-in-germany) 'career guidance services for all citizens at any stage of their lives'.  I would suggest availing yourself of these services, maybe engaging a career counsellor.

Comment: I'm confused why you're upset at having fewer things to do. Is this in-office work? Do they require you to be in your seat a specific number of hours a day? If so, then can you just tell them (in writing) whenever you have no more work to do, and do your own work (like looking for jobs) at that point? If not, then can you just leave early when you've finished the day's work?

Comment: You refused to resign, and then you put in your notice period... which is an action you do when you resign. So did you resign or not? If you refused to resign, the alternative is to be fired, which isn't what is happening here.

Comment: @Nelson it could be "forced resignation" (aka "fired"), thus OP still has to follow the "notice period".

Comment: @Nelson OP said "put ***on*** a notice period", not "they put ***in*** their notice period".

Comment: This may actually be a benefit.  Then there is no doubt regarding whether you take the latest confidential information to your new employer or not - if you're not told, you can't.  Be certain to keep your side of the contract to the letter.

Comment: @Brondahl the OP did not "**put on** a notice period". He "**was put on** a notice period". By the company.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ .... yes "to be put on a notice period". That's what I said. What full sentence are you imagining that I was claiming? The sentence "Tom put on a notice period" does not have any meaning - an employee cannot put on a notice period ... they can only *be* (or were, or was, or will be, or could have been) put on a notice period

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood

Answer (score 77):

**Yes** - they can absolutely do that, and in instances where the employment relationship has significantly broken down (regardless of whose "fault" that is) it's actually pretty sensible to do that, or at the very least to strictly limit which meetings the employee is in. And no, that doesn't equate to being put on gardening leave either.

Really though I wouldn't let it get under your skin - you're on notice and you know that the amount of time you're going to be in this employment situation is going to be finite. Do what they ask you to do and spend the rest of your energy on finding a new job, assuming you haven't got one lined up yet. Look forward not back, this will be over before you know it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that cut-and-dry. This behaviour sounds like it might be interpreted as "bullying" at least by the standards set out in my company's HR policy document on such matters, which I'm assuming is fairly standard - but IANAL and IAN in Germany...

Comment: @komodosp On the flip side, if you know that someone is imminently about to leave the company, then you don't want them sitting in on meetings about the company's Strategic Plan, or any Confidential information.  Given the… *notable* number of other questions this user has posted about their work for this company, it might even be that HR are the ones advising to keep them out of meetings, as damage-mitigation.

Comment: @Chronocidal if it's about security, they should just send OP on leave. I suspect they're trying to make OP terminate the notice period early.

Comment: @komodosp: Indeed it isn't that cut-and-dried in all circumstances. In the UK at least, if an employer puts restrictions on an employee that make it effectively impossible for the employee to continue in their job, that may be _constructive dismissal_ which would leave the employer open to legal action from the employee.

Comment: @komodosp, Let's assume it is bullying. What should the OP do about it? Raise a stink with HR and fight the company? To what end?

Comment: It looks like they are simultaneously demanding that OP document their work, and also trying to prevent OP from doing any work. I assume they are trying to somehow get around the notice period. I am not from Germany, so I don't know whether that's possible or what OP should do.

Comment: I'd be inclined to fill in the timesheet with notes like "Attempted to complete task X, made little progress because I wasn't at meeting Y".

Comment: @MichaelKay And if you wanted to be more pointed about that: "Attempted to complete task X, made no progress because I wasn't ***allowed to be*** at meeting Y, which is a requirement for completing task X"

Comment: @GlennWillen you don't have to go to meetings to document and hand over existing work you did. It's unlikely they are restricting them from meetings relevant to any hand over, more likely they are restricted from meetings about new work. If they are restricting them from meetings relevant to hand over then they are only hurting themselves.

Comment: Note that in many jurisdictions looking for a new job during notice period working hours is perfectly okay.

Comment: Thanks all. The company is a startup and has no HR department. I have been restricted from meetings such as dailies, which means that if I have any blockers, it's harder and slower for me to get them resolved. The CEO threatened to fire me during my notice period if I didn't resign. I called his bluff and waited until he terminated my contract.

Answer (score 27):

They can exclude you from every meeting/activity that is not protected by law (like Betriebsratswahl, Betriebsversammlung or Betriebsratssitzungen - if you are a member).

Just be diligent to write down if you are hampered in your work by restricted access to resources (like Git) or information from meetings. Else there is very little to do.

Comment: Can they exclude a software engineer from scrum/stand up meetings when those meetings are important for resolving blockers, discussing tasks etc.?

Answer (score 5):

Meetings serve a purpose. Usually the purpose is to keep you up-to-date with future plans of the company, long term development and so on.

There are lots of things discussed in meetings where having you there doesn't benefit the company at all, because you won't ever see the outcome of these future plans, the long term development and so on. And since you are leaving soon, they reduce their risk by not informing you about these things.

Companies also do things to keep employees, like an outing, some event for all employees, Christmas party and so on. Since you have given notice, they are not going to keep you and spending money on this doesn't serve any purpose.

So are there any meetings where it would benefit the company that you are present? That's the question.

Comment: "Meetings serve a purpose. Usually the purpose is to keep you up-to-date with future plans of the company, long term development and so on." - this is a very one-sided definition of meetings. In more general terms, the purpose of a meeting is to distribute and interpret information. This information might be about the company's future plans, but it might just as well focus on learning what the OP has recently been working on. I can imagine various reasons why the OP may be kept out of different kinds of meetings, but claiming that each meeting is about informing employees about the ...

Comment: ... confidential future business plans of the company is an oversimplification.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Meetings are almost invariably "for" the future though, in the sense that the company expects to get more value from future work if those employees are in that meeting than they would have gotten from those same employees not having a meeting and instead using that time to continue working. Even something like a review or retrospective is explicitly looking at what happened in the past, but the *benefit* of it is in changing what happens in the future. A lot of them will not provide much benefit to the company for a soon-to-depart employee to attend.

Comment: @Ben: In everything you enumerate, the *outcome* of the meeting may be for the future, but the *input* required to reach that outcome in the first place is provided by those taking part at present. And typically, not just by one participant, but mutually, by everyone participating in the meeting. Now, as I wrote, there may be any number of reasons as for why the OP here specifically is not deemed a valuable addition for any of these meetings, but as a general definition of what the purpose of a meeting is, the focus on the subset of meetings that is just there to inform employees about ...

Comment: ... news from the company, top-down-style, is decidedly too narrow.

Comment: O. R. The last meeting I was in was a stand up meeting. In that meeting things got heated because my manager refused to repeat what he said after I asked him to clarify. I also solved a task using solution A and they wanted me to do it using solution B even though I already tried solution B and couldn't get it working without my manager's help. They also refused to jump/pair on a call to show how to do it with solution B. It turns out they was a data structure in the code base I need to use in order to make solution B work. Manager expected me to know that this data structure existed.